# Blueimp file uploader is throwing error "No conversion from text to Iframe" in IE 9 and above

Tags: asp.net, blueimp

Blueimp File uploader is throwing error `No conversion from text to Iframe` in IE 9 and above. It is working in Mozilla, Chrome and safari. I googled but I didn't find any error related to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem get solved by adding reference of js `jquery.iframe-transport.js` above the `Blueimp File uploader` js. This js is available in bundle of Blueimp File uploader zip file.

Comment: Mark this as an accepted answer. It worked for me, thanks.